# p:fileUpload not updating value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having trouble getting a `p:fileUpload` to work within a `ui:repeat` in PrimeFaces 6.2. I have the following:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="listForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{view.a.bList}" var="b">
        <p:fileUpload value="#{b.image}" mode="simple"/>
    </ui:repeat>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{view.submit}"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

```
public void submit() {
    for(B b : a.getBList()) {
        if(b.getImage() != null) {
            try {
                FileUtilities.saveFile(b.getImage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

The following is in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With all the relevant dependencies in my pom.xml. What am I missing to use a simple `p:fileUpload`?